# How to assert two nested property names are valid in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have the following type:

```
  type X = {
    a: {
      b: Data;
    };
    aa: {
      bb: Data;
    };
  }
```

I'd like to do something like this:

```
const data: X = {...};

function useData(arg1: 'a' | 'aa', arg2: 'b' | 'bb') {
   // assert that arg1 and arg2 are a valid combination

   // do something with X[arg1][arg2]
}
```

Is there a way to write a type assertion that can confirm `X[arg1][arg2]` is valid?  If it was just one layer deep, it would be easy, but I can't figure out the syntax for the extra layer.

Even if I'm comfortable that it's a valid combination (I could easily check in Javascript), I need to let the typescript compiler know.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the keyof to depends on another Type.And of course you can nest it like an array :)

here is an example code:

```
type Data = object;

type X = {
  a: {
    b: Data;
  };
  aa: {
    bb: Data;
  };
}

function useData<T extends keyof X, Z extends keyof X[T]>(arg1: T, arg2: Z) {
  // assert that arg1 and arg2 are a valid combination
  // do something with X[arg1][arg2]
}

useData('a', 'b'); // valid
useData('aa', 'bb'); // valid
useData('a', 'bb'); //invalid
useData('aa', 'b'); // invalid
```

Playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQ4FwTwBwU2ARAhmRwC8wD2AjAVjAYzAG4AoUYc0SWYADXWAG8qLEAuZ1i4bTpFGR7AAvkJ6IOXYSGx8EyROIpjuI0twBmAVwB2RAJaZdwbQGcYAxAB4AKsBgAPMDF0ATM8ADWMCJk30ADTAAFoOzq4e3r7+9ADatgC6AHwAFIgATgDmAIyctsGZWQBMnCEAlNKgAPTVwIhmFhlg4AAWyPXZOfXunSWdcKgAbogANgZuwASYALbYBrrIRroaFLXAbpjAZrMwYK0LWcAA7gb78UU5iXFFxYlU6lTmloqpAOSIb8Fv2G-lxMB1iNxm4nhYrO9JF9gD9fv9AXVgRMwS8UJDobC-gDagskaCQM8IR9Pt84di6rixsigA